# Isolate Dual-Boot Windows OS's - Encryption Programs

Tags: encryption, windows-10, bitlocker, hard-drive

**My machine has**

| Name | Model | Disk No. | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SDD | LITEON L8H | 0 | 240 GB |
| HDD | HGST | 1 | 1 TB ( 932 Gb ) |

SDD contains: Windows 10 (for work)

HDD contains:

```
Partition 1 /
├─ Files ( text , imgs , video , other )
├─ System Backups 
Partition 2/
├─ Boot Loader ( Grub )
├─ Windows 10
```

I'd like to use my HDD as a sandbox, just for games and other stuff.

And the SSD contains sensitive data and I don't want it to leak to my HDD (sandbox).

---

##### What I Need

A way to completely **isolate** the drives from each other so there is no way for malware to spread from to the other.

To be even more clear, suppose I'm intentionally going to infect one HDD with malware, so I need to make sure that it is impossible for it to spread to my other drive/s.

##### I'm not looking for a solution like:

- Use a VM (Virtual Machine)

For simple tasks, I would use a VM but for gaming / and other stuff that requires full baremetal performance.

- Unplug the SSD when you're booting into the HDD

I'm using/running a laptop so that wouldn't be efficient even with a desktop; I risk damaging the components.

---

I did a bit of research and found out encrypting the drive might help using Windows BitLocker. Is BitLocker good for my situation?

Some say it's a bad idea and BitLocker doesn't work on SSD's?
[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/you-cant-trust-bitlocker-to-encrypt-your-ssd-on-windows-10/)

> Even if you enable BitLocker encryption on a system, Windows 10 may not actually be encrypting your data. Instead, Windows 10 may be relying on your SSD to do it, and your SSD’s encryption may be easily broken.

Is it true? There are updates on the topic but I don't want to risk it. I need something that guarantees secure encryption.

Comment: So, are you looking to isolate drives, or are you settled on full drive encryption as a solution?

Comment: I'm looking to isolate the drives , I'm still looking for better solution than  full drive encryption  - im thinking disabling the drive when the system boots maybe i still don't know what the most efficient way to do it

Comment: If you installed windows on , let's say drive 0 and installed 2n'd windows on drive 1 -- when you boot to either  windows 1 or 2 -- windows recognize all the disks(partitions) on your drive as a available space to store data even if it contains a OS files